# How to double the pixel size of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, scale

I have a canvas of the size 320*200 pixels.
Now I want to double the size of the pixels, resulting in a 640*400 display.
I don't want it to have a higher pixel resolution, just everything doubled (bigger visible pixels).

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: It may be better to explain why a question should be down-voted. This is a legit question. Probably down-voted because its been asked before. But still its not poorly asked.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that Brenwell, I was a bit puzzled about this as well. I'll make sure to double check for any question already asked before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the resolution with the height and width properties, while adjusting the size's display trough the style.

```
<canvas width="320" height="200" style="width:640px;height:400px;"></canvas>
```